# Underlying explanation of simple calc benchmark

Tags: go

The following benchmarks performs best on the one with a function operating the calculation. Even if it inlines, why does it perform better?

```
func add1(i int) int {
    return i + 1
}

var x = 0

func BenchmarkAdd1(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        x = x + 1
    }
}

func BenchmarkAdd1ForceType(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        x = x + int(1)
    }
}

func BenchmarkIncrement(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        x++
    }
}

func BenchmarkAdd1WithFunction(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        x = add1(x)
    }
}


 BenchmarkAdd1-8                         1000000000               1.99 ns/op
 BenchmarkAdd1ForceType-8                2000000000               1.96 ns/op
 BenchmarkIncrement-8                    2000000000               2.02 ns/op
 BenchmarkAdd1WithFunction-8             2000000000               0.44 ns/op
```

CPU is `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz`

Go version `1.9.2 darwin/amd64`

Comment: Your add call is constant.  It's called with a constant and adds a constant.  Did you mean `x = add1(x)`?

Comment: Wait, scratch that, you're using i as the value.  Still, it doesn't mimic the other tests, since it's using the increment var instead of x itself.

Comment: Was a typo. Updated the addition and results

Comment: Now you're back to adding a constant to a constant, which means the compiler can replace that entire function call with `x = 2`.

Comment: Wow, edits like crazy.  Ok, now we're in business.

Comment: Running your code on my machine, after your edits, I get nearly identical run times for all of them.  So if it's still doing it on yours, it's some optimization trick the compiler is pulling that's short-cutting part of the operation.

Comment: Yes that's why I noted my CPU. We probably get different optimised assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gets optimized away. If you do something with `x` after the loop, you'll find they all perform about the same:

```
var buf = new(bytes.Buffer)

func add1(i int) int {
    return i + 1
}

func BenchmarkAdd1(b *testing.B) {
    var x = 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        x = x + 1
    }
    fmt.Fprintln(buf, x)
}

func BenchmarkAdd1ForceType(b *testing.B) {
    var x = 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        x = x + int(1)
    }
    fmt.Fprintln(buf, x)
}

func BenchmarkIncrement(b *testing.B) {
    var x = 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        x++
    }
    fmt.Fprintln(buf, x)
}

func BenchmarkAdd1WithFunction(b *testing.B) {
    var x = 0
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        x = add1(x)
    }
    fmt.Fprintln(buf, x)
}
```

This yields:

```
BenchmarkAdd1-4                 2000000000           0.34 ns/op
BenchmarkAdd1ForceType-4        2000000000           0.33 ns/op
BenchmarkIncrement-4            2000000000           0.34 ns/op
BenchmarkAdd1WithFunction-4     2000000000           0.35 ns/op
```

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. Then they're all equally the same. Was just a small thing I was wondering :)

Comment: I don't know why it's optimized away in the last case but not in the others - just a quirk of the compiler I guess.

Comment: Ya, for benchmarks, it's always a good idea to assign the variable you're using to some other global variable _after_ the loop, as it prevents the compiler from optimizing out the entire loop due to the result value not actually being used.

Comment: Exactly as @Kaedys says. See the end of [this post by Dave Cheney](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go).

Comment: That's a good thing to know! I had that with LittleEndian operations too. Maybe I should rerun some old benchmarks too with this knowledge :)

Comment: Incidentally, if you put `x` as a function-level variable instead of a package global, it _massively_ cuts down run time (2ns to 0.3ns on mine), because it allows `x` to be allocated on the stack instead of the heap.  Just make sure you still assign the final value to a package-level variable after the loop.

Comment: Makes sense! :D

Comment: Indeed - that's what I did in the sample code in the answer. It actually brought the other 3 benchmarks in line with the last one, instead of slowing the last one to match the first two.